# Android Cursor Loader only works once

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I'm using cursor loaders to load data from my content providers and not always getting results.  On my initial call to the content loader it returns the correct results:

```
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(
                LOADER_LOCATION_INFO, null, this);
```

However when I run this query again (using the same code above)  I do not get any results.  The loader callback is not called.

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    switch(arg0){
    case (LOADER_LOCATION_INFO):
        return new CursorLoader(this, 
                               //my query

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor arg2) {
    switch (loader.getId()) {
    case (MY_CASE):
        doSomething(arg2);
        break;
    }   
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

};
```

I don't know if it matters, but I am also making calls to the loaderManager from a fragment inside this activity as well.  Those queries work fine.
What would cause this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was with the Loader IDs.  I have LoaderCallbacks in several fragments and the parent activity.  I was declaring the IDs in each fragment/activity using static final ints.  I was using the same IDs.  I moved all the IDs to the parent activity and made them unique.  This fixed the issue.